# Problems with importing external module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I tried to download an external module to test how it works, by simply downloading 'Simplejson' using pip in cmd(Window). I watched my teacher did it, and followed it the exact way but i ran into a problem.

Not sure what i did, because my teacher just told me to follow him, i think we created a virtual environment on python so that we can do more than one projects with various versions of python. Anyway, most of you will know that after creating a virtual environment in my folder that i work for coding, a 3 new folders will appear and 'Simplejson' will be inside Lib\site-packages. Even if i checked that Simplejson is still inside the file, some how i can not import it. Are there any way that i can solve it?

enter image description here

Comment: Without any other details about your scenario I would assume that you are also trying to execute your program with VS Code. If that's true double check your .json configuration generate by it and see if editor is using the Python from you virtualenv. If you're not using VS Code to execute and rather running on CMD/Powershell then make sure you either sourced/activated the virtual environment (activate.bat) or is making actual reference to the Python from you virtualenv folder.

Comment: @douglas_min -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following to check the process of installing and using the module "Simplejson" in VS Code:

1. Please check whether the python currently used by the VS Code terminal is the same as the one displayed in the lower left corner of the VS Code: (`python --version` or `pip --version`)

   [image]

   (If they use different pythons, please open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment.)
2. Then install the module "[Simplejson](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/)".
3. Check the installed modules: (`pip show Simplejson`)

   [image]

Run:

[image]

Reference: [Python Environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).